# Would it be possible to respond "Not" if someone ask me that "Do you ~", or "Did you ~"?

Tags: conversation

Is it alright that I say just a word "Not." about the question starting with "Do you~?", or "Did you~?"? (Not Are you~?, Were you~?)

Comment: If you respond "Not" I would know that English is not your native language.  But I would (probably ) understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you know how to swim?
>
> Not. *(incorrect)*
>
> ---
>
> Do you know how to swim?
>
> No. *(correct)*
>
> ---
>
> Do you know how to swim or not?
>
> Not. *(acceptable but usually considered to be an attempt at mild humour)*